# textview shrinking in landscape view when keyboard appears ios

Tags: ios, ipad, view, uiscrollview, landscape

Full size of textview in landscape view
[image]

Shrinked textview when keyboards appears in landscape view
[image]

Comment: what are you doing when keyboard appears. in keyboardWillShow method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give constraints to your textview(for landscape mode).
Refer Autolayouts https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-202/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the size class  Compact Width | Any Height combination and add the AutoLayout Constraints